# Grid floor suddenly disappeared

Tags: 3d-view

[image]i was working on a project and my floor grid disappeared. I looked in the overlays menu and the checkbox is enabled so i don't know what caused it and how to bring it back.

Comment: Welcome, please check the scale value below the checkbox in the overlays menu. It's default value is 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

When *Grid* and *Floor* are enabled in the *Overlays*, there are two other possible reasons for it to disappear:

1. As @tetii already mentioned in the comments, the *Scale* in the *Overlays* is set to a different (most probably higher) value than the default 1.
2. The *Unit Scale* which you find under *Scene Properties* > *Units* is set to a different (most probably lower) value than the default 1.

*Scale* setting in the *Overlays*:

[image: overlays scale]

*Unit Scale* in the *Scene Properties*:

[image: unit scale]

As you can see in the comparison below, a higher *Grid Scale* or a lower *Unit Scale* both result in a seemingly disappearing grid floor. Seemingly, because zooming out probably brings it back, depending on how much the value is and when the camera is clipping.

[image: grid comparison]

Comment: From what i saw the scale is exactly the same as the one you have. Right now, if i put the the perspective view i can see strips of the grid only in one direction but in orthographic view i don't see it at all

Comment: @Ana Okay, I see... maybe change the clipping distances? In the _3D Viewport_ sidepanel (shortcut N), in the _View_ tab - what values are there for _Clipping Start_ & _End_?

Comment: they are 0.01m to 1000m

Comment: @Ana Seems okay... maybe you have accidentally activated a clipping border. Try pressing Alt+B in the viewport. Do you have this problem generally in Blender or in a certain file? Maybe you should then upload that file at https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. Maybe you reset the grid color with a "Backspace". Reset the theme settings, go to *Edit > Preferences > Themes > Reset* (in a upper right corner).

[image]